# Log4j size and Time based appender

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j

I am using log4j for logging purpose as follows

```
log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=C:log/app-log%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

This configuration creates log file on daily basis and because of that log file grows up to certain GB and it creates problem.I need to roll log file on the basis of size and time. Can you please suggest me configuration for the same.

Answer (score 0):

[DailyRollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) may help.

log file will be rolled depends on below DatePattern.

See: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/applog.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```